# SSH Without Password: martin@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh

for the last hours, I tried setting up my old laptop ("Remote"), which is currently running Fedora31 to be a testdevice, that I can SSH into, WITHOUT PASSWORD. To achieve my goal, I followed several guides online.
The laptop that I use productivly is running Ubuntu18.04LTS ("Host").

The online-guides go as follows:

1. Make sure OpenSSH-server is up and running on remote.
2. SCP your public-key from your Host to the Remote
3. Paste the Publickey on the Remote into the authorized_keys file `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

So far, so good. First, I removed the know_hosts file on Host. When I SSH from Host to Remote, i get prompted with the ECDSA Message, if I want to continue and add the IP to my "know_hosts" file. Also, I need to provide the password. Everything works so far. But I don't want to enter my password.
Therefore, I edit the sshd-config on Remote `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. 
I set `PasswordAuthentication no`, saved the file and restarted the ssh service with `sudo systemctl restart sshd`.

If I try to login from Host to Remote, i get the errormessage from the question title
`martin@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

---

**Already tried fixes:**

On Remote:

Setting the Read-rights as follows and restart the sshd service with `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

```
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If your username on the remote server is not the same as on your client then you might need to specify the identity file.  Anyway, this worked for me.

```sh
ssh remotename@remoteserver -i localprivatekeyfile
```